# Ignore criteria that's empty. Is there a way?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, criteria, sumifs

I have a sheet that's searching for 4 criteria's. The Problem is that not all the criteria's are filled with data. I want Excel to continue the formula and ignore the empty cell.

How can i make this happen?

[image]

`=SUMIFS(Data!$K$2:$K$9999;Data!$M$2:$M$9999;">="&B$2;Data!$E$2:$E$9999;B$4;Data!$AA$2:$AA$9999;">="&B$8;Data!$G$2:$G$9999;'Employee''s'!$A10)`

Comment: I do not understand, this formula will only add where all four criteria are met, are you asking to sum where the criteria is also blank?

Comment: Not sure, but I think OP means *where range of criteria is met OR is blank* both at same time.

Comment: See the picture. The criteria's are "prijs boven", "Afdeling", "Goederengroep", "Marge boven". When i fill all the criteria's it works fine. But when i empty one of them the result is 0. I want Excel to ignore the empty criteria and continue the formula.

Comment: Could you not just stick a wildcard on the end of the string like `&"*"` then it can find anything when the cell is blank? - not sure whether that fit's the search criteria when it is not blank though...

Comment: Or you could stick `len(A1) > 0 ` in your sumifs function

Comment: Still not working :( I Think Dominique has the right answer but i dont know how to integrate in my formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `OR()` and `ISBLANK()` worksheet functions for creating such a criterion, as you can see from following example (As criterion, I use `Ax=2`):

```
 |    A      B                      C
-+----+------+-----------------------
1|   2|  TRUE|  =OR(ISBLANK(A1);A1=2)
2|   1| FALSE|  =OR(ISBLANK(A2);A2=2)
3|    |  TRUE|  =OR(ISBLANK(A3);A3=2)
```

Comment: Sorry i'm not an Excel expert. I think i understand what you are saying but how do i integrate it in my formula?